# Grails Create Critera and Listing single or specified column/s value only?

Tags: grails, createcriteria

I grails i m trying to fetch a lookup value from the database and i want to list a list of single column value that is "Value" column .

```
    private Static Final String Custom = "Custom"  //lie in class Constants

    LookUp.createCriteria.list() { 

    eq('type',LookupTypeEnum.valueOf(Constants.Custom).toString())



   }
```

this listing was like select ,

how can i make this query into

```
   Select Value from LookUp where Type = 'Custom'
```

i want my grails query to return me a single query result like the sql. 
I want to bind it to a list box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad this do all the trick , 
       private Static Final String Custom = "Custom"  //lie in class Constants
      //LookupTypeEnum is Enum collection implementation class if don't have it simply you can   replace it with your value ="Custom" or a variable Constants.Custom

```
  LookUp.createCriteria.list() { 
  eq('type',LookupTypeEnum.valueOf(Constants.Custom).toString())
  projections {  //projection does the trick
   property('value')
 }
```

}

It's equivalent SQl select query is :

```
select value from lookup where type='custom' ;
```